# using decode with input as comma separated list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This could be simple question for experts.

Here is my requirement.  I have to use `DECODE` and match the string containing comma separated values.

Here is sample SQL:  `'A'` is column value from table, `'A,B'C'` is comma separated string passed as expression to sql

```
SELECT DECODE('A' , 'A,B,C', 'true', 'false') FROM DUAL;
```

The above SQL should return true as csv expression contains `'A'`.

Please help me writing this SQL

Comment: Why do you "have to" use DECODE for this? (Do you really have to?) Also - are the inputs and the table values all single letters? Or could you also have to compare 'A' to the string 'A,BC,X,YS'? If it's the latter, watch out for any solution based on `instr` or regexp of some sort only. The letter L will be found in the input 'ABC,KLM, XY', which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to determine if a string is within another string?

```
select case when instr( 'A,B,C', 'A' ) > 0 
         then 'True' 
         else 'False' 
       end 
from dual
```

Add the DECODE version

```
  select decode( instr( 'A,B,C', 'A' ), 0, 'False', 'True' )
  from dual
```

Comment: Thanks, but can we attain using DECODE? It's because DECODE is using in existing sql which previously get's only one value.  But now the value is comma separated string

Comment: Thanks BobC.  Appreciate if you provide me SQL having 'A' (column value) first and expression (comma separated value) as second in DECODE statement.  This is how my whole SQL is built and I don't want to change much

Comment: This example gave incorrect result   `code  SELECT DECODE(INSTR('BA,C,D', 'A'), 0, 'False', 'True' ) FROM DUAL  code`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `decode()`.  Use the ANSI standard `CASE` statement.  The answer to your question is that you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ',' || 'A,B,C' || ',' LIKE '%,' || 'A' || ',%'           
             THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'
        END)
FROM DUAL;
```

Note:  The string concatenation is just because I suspect the values are variables.  The simpler form is:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ',A,B,C,' LIKE '%,A,%'           
             THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'
        END)
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DECODE, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT DECODE(INSTR('A,B,C', 'A'), 0, 'false', 'true') FROM DUAL;
```

where
`INSTR('Comma separated string', 'column value to match')` will return 0 if the column value is not in the comma separated string. In your example, 
`INSTR('A,B,C', 'A')` will return a value greater than 0 and `INSTR('D,B,C', 'A')` will return 0. So then DECODE can check if the return value of INSTR() is 0 then return false otherwise return true.

Comment: Thanks much.  However, my comma separated string will always appear as expression for e.g.    SELECT DECODE ('A', 'A,B,C', 'true', 'false') FROM DUAL

Comment: This example gave incorrect result     `code` SELECT DECODE(INSTR('BA,C,D', 'A'), 0, 'False', 'True' ) FROM DUAL `code